# How can I share files in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, networking

I have one laptop and about 20 PCs that have Ubuntu 16.04 installed and they are all connected to a LAN network. I want to make 20 folders on the laptop and share them such that:

- Each PC has access to its allocated folder only.
- Whatever changes are made to the folder or the files inside a folder from the PC, will also affect the folder in the laptop.
- In case I turn the PC off and on I will still be able to see and access the folder from the PC.

Basically what I'm trying to do is fail-safe mechanism so that if something happens to a computer and it breaks, the information on it doesn't have to get lost because I have it on the laptop.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: 1 Cloud Folder, all Laptops Syncing with it no good?

Comment: A file-system can be shared, my choice approach would be via NFS, but it won't be the best for every use-case situation. For the shared folders to be visible for clients, the host must be powered & running (as I read it; you want the clients to see the server even if the server is off??)  The fail-safe mechanism can be setup in many ways (raid, duplicate or backup machine) but you seem to want a solution for file-serving roles with the server being optional, or I'm confused... Is this for a classroom?

Comment: It is for a classroom yes. I want each PC to have access to its allocated folder only, I don't want students to see each others folders. Also the laptop will be on all the time. So, I want the fail-safe mechanism to be viable while the laptop is on. I know that it's not reasonable to do that if the laptop is off.

Comment: I'll recommend to use [LTSP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP) - you have server and PXE-booted clients. The client mounts home folder via SSHFS from server.